# Trigger upon change in formula field result

Tags: trigger, formula-field, dml

I have standard object - ServiceContract, on which there is a formula field Status__c.

Lets assume the formula field does this "StartDate__c>=Today>=EndDate__c, status=Active, else status=Expired"

StartDate__c and EndDate__c are Date fields on Service contract. They don't change.

I want to trigger a code when status__c changes from Active to Expired. Any suggestions on how can we do that?

Writing an update trigger on Service contract doesn't help. Changes in formula field results are not caught in triggers.

Another option is to have a batch job that runs periodically and checks if there is any ServiceContract with Status=Expired. But i want to avoid that.

It would be better if somehow i can invoke a trigger.

Comment: Is quantity a rollup field?

Comment: What is Quantity__c and is it on ServiceContract? Can't you just write a trigger based on Quantity__c?

Comment: Sorry for giving a poor example. I will discuss the actual scenario .... For now Its a combination of StartDate__c and EndDate__c. If today()>=StartDate and today()<EndDate__c, we consider the Status=Active. 

So StartDate__c and EndDate__c are fields on ServiceContract. They are fixed dates. When the endDate passes, we consider Status__c as "Expired"

Now as soon as Status goes from "Active" to "Expired", i need some sort of trigger.

Comment: triggers require the sobject to be subject to a C(r)UD operation and the mere passage of time isn't good enough unless you have set up time-based workflows that do field updates; alternatively, you can have a scheduled (batch) job sweep your sobject every day looking for records that meet your criteria